# NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription required, but bluetooth is not used

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions, xcode11

In my ios app with new Xcode 11 GM Seed 2 after deploy, apple returned error:
**ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist** with NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription?language=objc readed.

The problem is that I don't use bluetooth in my app. Or maybe I don't know about it. How can I find out why this permission purpose is needed?

I'm not using `CoreBluetooth.framework`

Comment: Check Linked Frameworks and Libraries section for all targets (Project target as well as pod targets). To find which target uses the Bluetooth feature.

Comment: @AbhiYaduwanshi i have 30+ items under Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content. Where is it wrote if bluetooth is using?

Comment: Check if there is any framework named CoreBluetooth.framework

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. My code and also SDKs don't use the bluetooth.

Comment: This just started happening for my app today. We already had `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` set but it seems like `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` has now become required (we haven't updated any code or plugins so this must be a change at Apple's end)

Comment: We also started getting this as of this morning, without (to the best of our knowledge) any CoreBluetooth references.

Comment: Look for things like advertising frameworks; admob is definitely one that triggers this. This is part of iOS 13 clamping down on companies using Bluetooth to track user location without telling them.

Comment: I fixed this problem by searching "bluetooth" keyword in Workspace. And I found it used in the 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit' pod. So I removed this pod as I don't use in the app. Problem solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this exact same issue today. When I did a grep search I found that there is some reference to CoreBluetooth.framework inside my project.pbxproj

I removed the reference and building the app went fine. Uploaded to Apple and it got through so this worked for me.

To search use the following command

```
grep -r -a CoreBluetooth.framework ProjectFolder
```

Comment: Clearly showed where CoreBluetooth.framework is referred to in our project. Can confirm it went through after removing the reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Maurice Shouldn't we use only the name of the framework (without extension) for accurate result : grep -r -a CoreBluetooth ProjectFolder?

Comment: Yes if you want to find everything related to CoreBluetooth you can do that. However I only wanted to search with the extension. -a treats files as text. -r makes it recursive

Comment: I did a search without the .framework and couldn't find any other stuff. But it might be different for your project.

Answer (score 6):

Open your Info.plist and add a `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`. You can do this in the editor by adding a line item like this:

[image: Screenshot of info.plist with NSBluetoothAlwaysUsadeDescription as the key and explanation text as the String value]

Or you can right click on the Info.plist and Open As -> Source Code and paste in the two appropriate lines as xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ....
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We use Bluetooth to connect to the MantisX hardware device.</string>
    ....
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: The question is asked when the app doesn't use Bluetooth, so adding this description may lead to confusion in the future

Answer (score 5):

I was able to snuff out CoreBluetooth usages by scanning for symbol usages, specifically looking for `CBCentralManager`. The script I wrote to do so:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# find-bluetooth-usages.sh <app1.app> <app2.app> ...

check_references_corebluetooth() {
  nm "$1" | grep "CBCentralManager" 2>&1 >/dev/null
}

find_usages () {
  app_path=$1
  if [[ ! -d $app_path || ! -d "$app_path/Frameworks" ]]; then
    echo "$app_path is not a valid app directory."
    exit 1
  fi
  app_filename=$(basename -- "$app_path")
  app_name="${app_filename%.*}"

  if check_references_corebluetooth "$app_path/$app_name"; then
    echo "$app_name contains references to CoreBluetooth"
  fi
  for framework_filename in $(ls "$app_path/Frameworks" | egrep '\.framework$'); do
    framework_path="$app_path/Frameworks/$framework_filename"
    framework_name=$(basename "$framework_path" .framework)
    if check_references_corebluetooth "$framework_path/$framework_name"; then
      echo "$framework_name contains references to CoreBluetooth"
    fi
  done
}

for arg in "$@"; do
  find_usages "$arg"
done
```

This will dig through the main binary + its included frameworks to find `CBCentralManager` references. Ex:

`./find-bluetooth-usages.sh /path/to/MyApp.app`

Answer (score 2):

A third party library/framework/pod in your app might be using CoreBluetooth. Just add `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` in your Info.plist, error will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes</string>
```

Comment: How is this different from Marc's answer?

Comment: i tried it in swift 5 its working for me so its easy to understand i mention the word swift5

Comment: Sure. But, it needs to add some value to the table. Your answer does not. I think you should delete this answer before someone reports it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wasn't using any bluetooth related API but app was crashing because of this. And I found out that Google Mobile Ads was using bluetooth. I made sure of this by removing it from pods and rerunning the app. (I think we all should ask Google to why they need bluetooth to show mobile ads)

Anyways, you can stop your app from crashing by adding `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` to your plist for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your app has a deployment target earlier than iOS 13, add the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key to your app’s Information Property List file in addition to NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key as one or more of third party in your project uses bluetooth functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple has made some policy changes. Otherwise, it is weired to ask for non-used flags. It is very concerning.
I also got my apps rejected for these reasons, all the while older versions are running without this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Maurice's answer, with and without `.framework` extension, but did not find any reference to `CoreBluetooth` in my project.
I also had previously in `Info.plist` file added: "`Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description`", with String Value: "`App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes"`".
This didn't work either.
Finally after seeing Chase Roberts's answer I added: "`NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`", with String value: "`App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes`".
After that this error was not shown again for my app while publishing.

**Note:** In warning for error: `ITMS-90683`, for my app was said that delivery was successful, but I can if I wish to make changes in regard to stated issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add both NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription and NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription to your Info.plist file. Your Info.plist file is located (by default) inside your prroject folder "Supporting Files" group and may be called something like {PROJECTNAME}-Info.plist. You have a couple of choices for adding it.
One choice is to just editthe file from the command line using vim or whatever. Then add these lines:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes</string>
```

The second choice is to double click that Info.plist file in XCode and use the "super helpful" XCode editor. This annoying editor does not actually have the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription in a dropdown list, you have to add it manually. Super helpful. Anyway there is a little plus button to the right of the Information Property List header, just click that. In step 1 you look for "Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description". That is the readable name for NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription. Then just click on the value part at the right and enter your text, like "App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes" or watever. Once that is done, click that same plus button again and you will get the same drpdown list. Ignore that list and just paste the string NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription there. Then click on the value to the right and paste "App would like to use your bluetooth for communication purposes".